# Python global variable is not working as expected

Tags: python

I'm just starting out with Python and experimenting with different solutions. I was working with global variables and I ran into something but don't know why it's doing what it's doing.

To start, I have two modules: test1 and test2. test1 is as follows:

```
import test2
num = 0
def start():
    global num
    num = num + 5
    print 'Starting:'
    print num
    test2.add()
    print 'Step 1:'
    print num
    test2.add()
    print 'Step 2:'
    print num
```

And test2 is this:

```
import test1
def add():
    test1.num = test1.num + 20
```

When I run test1.start() the output is:

> Starting:
>   5
>   Step 1:
>   25
>   Step 2:
>   45

Why doesn't test2 need the global declaration to modify the variable in test1? Line 5 in test1 requires it  at line 4, but if I remove both it still works (0, 20,40). I'm just trying to figure out why it's not working as I expected it to.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem begins at the second word in the title, and ends somewhere around the third. :-(

Comment: It's also not a good idea to modules import each other like that. You introduce a circular dependency.

Comment: I suggest you also start with [the tuturial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `global` declaration is not for *modifying* the name, it's for **rebinding** it. Since you are accessing the name via its module what you are doing is modifying the *module*.

Answer (score 0):

From test2's perspective, test1.num is a variable belonging to the module test1.

The `global` keyword only specifics that the scoping for that variable is module-level (i.e. not local).